# Using ursa (nodejs module) to generate a symmetric key?

Tags: node.js, encryption, rsa, encryption-symmetric

I'm using [`ursa`](https://github.com/quartzjer/ursa) (nodejs module) to do the following:

- Use a private key and someone else's public key to generate a symmetric key
- Encrypt some data with the symmetric key
- Encrypt the symmetric key with the user's public key

However, I can't seem to find any methods that allow me to create a symmetric key. My understanding is that simply generating a pseudo-random byte string should be good enough for the key, but then I can't use the rest of the method in `ursa` to actually encrypt anything because it's a random string and not a key/cert.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U**RSA** as the name suggests is an RSA implementation and as such doesn't not handle symmetric encryption. If you want those, then you can use node.js' native [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module which provides everything you need in this regard.

> - Encrypt the symmetric key with the user's public key

This means that the symmetric key is simply data. URSA doesn't have to know what this is.